# Garbage with strcpy and strcat

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy, strcat

I'm doing a client-server project in linux and I need to concatenate some strings.

I tried my code on visual studio in windows and it works fine, but it linux it gives me some garbage. I've got this function:

```
char* concat(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int tam = 0;
    tam = strlen(s1);
    tam += strlen(s2);
    char *resultado =  malloc(sizeof(char) * tam) ;
    strcpy(resultado, s1); 
    strcat(resultado, s2); 
    return resultado;
}
```

I read that the problem is the missing of `'\0'` and I've done that:

```
 char* concat(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int tam = 0;
    tam = strlen(s1);
    tam += strlen(s2);
    char *resultado =  malloc(sizeof(char) * tam) ;
    resultado[tam+1] = '\0';
    strcpy(resultado, s1); 
    strcat(resultado, s2); 
    return resultado;
}
```

The first 4 times that I called the function it works (the garbage disappeared), but then it gives me `malloc(): memory corruption

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You're allocating `tam` characters for `resultado`, and then add a `\0` character at `tam+1`. With array indices 0-based, that means you're 2 over the allocated limit.

Comment: It probably works in visual studio because it's generous, and allocates some memory beyond the limit you've set. But you can't rely on it, and running it in a debugger should throw an error.

Comment: Read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: If at least s1 has been `malloc()`ed before, you could **possibly** avoid copying s1 using `realloc()` with the additional length of s2 (remember to ensure there is space for an additional NUL terminator). Then just append s2 to the realloc`ed s1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not allocating space for the `nul` terminator, a very common mistake.

**Suggestions**:

1. Don't use `sizeof(char)` it's 1 by definition.
2. Check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL`.
3. Always remember the `nul` byte.

So your code would be fixed like this

```
char *resultado =  malloc(1 + tam);
if (resultado == NULL)
    pleaseDoNotUse_resultado();
```

Also, notice that this line

```
resultado[tam + 1] = '\0';
```

has multiple issues

1. `tam + 1` us outside the allocated block.
2. You don't need to do that, `strcpy()` will do it for you.

Using `strcat()` and `strcpy()` in this situation is inefficient, because you already know how many bytes to copy, this

```
char *concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    size_t l1;
    size_t l2;
    char  *resultado

    if ((s1 == NULL) || (s2 == NULL))
        return NULL;
    l1 = strlen(s1);
    l2 = strlen(s2);
    resultado =  malloc(1 + l1 + l2) ;
    if (resultado == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(resultado     , s1, l1); 
    memcpy(resultado + l1, s2, l2); 

    resultado[l1 + l2] = '\0';
    return resultado;
}
```

would be more efficient, even when you are checking for `NULL` like a paranoic freak, it would be faster than `strcpy()` and `strcat()`, because you will only compute the lengths once.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allocating memory to hold the termianting null. Remember, `strlen()` does not count the null-terminator while calculating the string length. Nevertheless, you need that space in the destination buffer to put the null terminator.

You should write

```
 char *resultado =  malloc(tam + 1) ;
```

Also,

```
 resultado[tam+1] = '\0';
```

is very wrong, because, array indexing is `0` based in C and here, you're overrunning the allocated memory (yes, even while allocating a size of `tam+1` also)  which will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You don't need that at all, you can get rid of that.

After that, as a side-note, as mentioned by Iharob also,

1. Check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.
2. In C standard,  `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to be `1`. No need of using it while calculating the size for `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate one byte more than the resulting string's length:

```
char *resultado =  malloc(tam + 1) ;
```

Functions `strcpy` and `strcat` take care about the terminating NUL, you don't have to add it manually.